# Locating Resource Bundle Property in Jasper Reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have written small java program to get practice with **Jasper Reports**.

*Below is my java program which will generate report and export to PDF.*

```
public class BaseReporter {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        try { 
        InputStream inputStream = BaseReporter.class.getResourceAsStream("/reports/helloworld.jasper");

        DataBeanMaker dataBeanMaker = new DataBeanMaker();
        ArrayList<DataBean> dataBeanList = dataBeanMaker.addDataBean();

        JRBeanCollectionDataSource JRbeancollectiondatasource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataBeanList);

        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parameters.put("Created By", "xxx");
        parameters.put("StylePath", "d:/Learn-WS/Jasper/src/reports/jr.jrtx");


        // Export to PDF
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(inputStream, parameters, JRbeancollectiondatasource);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "d:/Learn-WS/Jasper/src/reports/helloworld.pdf");

       System.out.println("report process completed ....");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And my package structure is

```
project
       src
          com
             BaseReport.java
             DataBean.java
             DataBeanMaker.java
          reports
             helloworld.jasper
             helloworld.jrxml
             jr.jrtx
          jr.properties
```

In the **jr.properties** file, i have added the property to be used in the report.
report.name="Testing Report"

I have included my resource bundle name in helloworld.jrxml file in the jasperReport tag with the attribute named **resourceBundle="jr"**.

I have called the resource bundle property in report as

```
<title>
        <band height="30">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="6fbe7eb7-04cd-4c03-bc6e-b2cda3026d3b" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="3" width="535" height="23"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[$R{report.name}]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
```

**But the resource bundle property is not loaded / located properly in the report.**

Kindly help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: I have find out a solution for the resource bundle locating in report file. In the report file *.jrxml file , we have use the tag **textFieldExpression** instead of tag **text**.

Answer (score 1):

I have find out a **solution** for the resource bundle locating in report file. In the report file *.jrxml file , we have use the tag **textFieldExpression** with the parent tag textField instead of tag **text** and it works well.

```
<title>
        <band height="30">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="ec4f36de-cf2b-4575-a585-3e860ad8faec" mode="Opaque" x="199" y="0" width="125" height="20" forecolor="#0000FF"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{report.name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
```